# What is a filled rectangle called, if anything?

Tags: geometry, terminology

In geometry, the set of points within a circle is called a disk (open disk if it excludes the boundary, closed disk if it includes it).

Is there a similar notion for squares or rectangles?

"A filled rectangle that includes the boundary is called a closed _______."

"A filled square that excludes the boundary is called an open ________."

Comment: In my experience "rectangle" refers to the interior, not the boundary, in most contexts.

Comment: @EricWofsey If that is the case, is there a term for just the boundary? A disk has a circle, a ball has a sphere, etc.

Comment: Rectangle technically refers to the boundary, considering a rectangle as a polygon, because "polygon" is typically defined as just the exterior.

Comment: I've generally understood *polygon* to mean the vertices and edges, and polygonal (e.g., triangular, rectangular, etc) *region* to include the interior.

Comment: “rectangular region”

Answer (score 2):

Yes! It is called a 2-cell; in general, a k-cell is a closed set of points (meaning that the boundaries are included) in k dimensions with "straight" boundaries. So a 3-cell is a filled in rectangular prism, a 1-cell is a closed interval, [a,b], and a 0-cell is a point.

Comment: It seems that this isn't explicitly limited to rectangular or even quadrilateral  objects. The 2-cell includes any filled polygon in 2 dimensions. This is close to the kind of terminology I'm looking for.

Comment: No, I think it's just a rectangular solid (see WP).

Comment: Wikipedia actually states "The facets of a polyhedron or plane tiling are its 2-faces." This includes more than just rectangular solids. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_(geometry)#Cell_or_3-face

Comment: I see what you mean. I was using the terminology of Rudin (cited on the k-cell WP page), but in the context of polyhedra and their higher-dimensional analogues, there seem to be other meanings.

Comment: Not every rectangle is a 2-cell.  For example, consider the subset of $\Bbb R^2$ for which $|x+y|\le 1$.  This is a region bounded by a rectangle.  (A square, in fact.)  But it is not a 2-cell.

Comment: What I mean is a rectangle is a 2-cell in the coordinate system it suggests, that is, with the origin at its center and the axes parallel to its sides.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a topological version, a filled square without borders is an  $\ell_\infty$ open ball, $\max (|x|,|y|)<1$.

[image: l_1, l_2 and l infinity balls]

Same with the rectangle, with some anisotropy.

Comment: While I understand that L-norms can be used this way to construct a square as a circle, that's not as satisfactory of an answer as I was hoping for. If I say an open ball, in general this implies $L_2$. Calling it an $L_\infty$ ball, while correct, isn't a distinct term from ball reserved for squares/rectangles.

Comment: @Axoren I guess you are more interested in a geometrical than a topological definition. I kinda with rectangle being filled: we talk about its area. I would not say area for a circle, but for a disk