# Terminology - How to differentiate a polygon which is a bounded region and a polygon which is the boundary of a bounded region?

Tags: geometry, terminology, circles, polygons, plane-geometry

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, a **circle** refers to a set of the form $\{(x,y)\mid (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2\}$ and a **disc** refers to a set of the form $\{(x,y)\mid (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2\leq r^2\}$. I am thankful that the terminology is crystal clear here.

What about other terminologies such as a square, or more generally, a polygon? Does a square only include the boundary points? More precisely, which one of the following is defined to be a square:

1. $\{(x,y)\mid -1\leq x\leq 1, -1\leq y\leq 1\}$, or
2. $\left([-1,1]\times\{\pm 1\}\right)\bigcup\left(\{\pm 1\}\times[-1,1]\right)$?

What is the name of the other set of the above two?

**Edit**: I was teaching my daughter ($2$ years old) and am surprised that most of her books call a disc a "circle". Likely those books are not written by professional mathematicians.

Comment: I agree with the comments on this previous question: [What is a filled rectangle called, if anything?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1760146/856) Your example 2 is a square / polygon, example 1 is a square region / polygonal region / filled square / filled polygon.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for a much shorter terminology, such as a disc for a filled circle.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider adjectives here. E.g. *solid* square vs. *empty* square.

Convex polytopes, and thus convex polygons too, are most often *assumed* to be defined as the hull of their vertices, i.e. as being the intersection of half-spaces. Then those would be solid, for sure.

--- rk

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So you mean a square is more like a disc (in the homeomorphic sense) and an empty square is more like a circle?

Comment: The problem also occurs when considering $n$-gons with $n$ towards infinity. When you keep the circumradius constant, then this approximates a disc (the body still being assumed). But when keeping the side length, then this approximates the infinite linear tiling $\mathbb{Z}$, Thus the body underneath most often becomes neglected. I.e. the interpretation highly depends on the assumptions being made, and those may vary with the context. - Therefore, whenever this makes a difference, you should make it clear explicitely. This is why I recommended the usage of adjectives.